# Alamofire : Rest api

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am using a private api to register users.

Api structure is liked this:

```
post data = {
            "email": "",
            "password": ""
        }

------------------------------------------
          return value = {
          "result": True,
          "message": "",
          "token": ""
          }
```

My code is:

```
    Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
        .responseString { response in        
                guard response.result.error == nil else {
                    print(response.result.error!)
                    return
                }
                print(response.result.value)
                if let value:String = response.result.value {
                    let post = JSON(value)
                    if let connection = post.dictionary {
                        let token = connection["token"]?.string
                        print(token)
                    }
                }
    }
```

reponse.result.value returns an HTML file and I can not get "result", "message" and "token" values. I tried several methods I find from github but couldn't get it work.

EDIT:

I managed to get response from the api:
SUCCESS: {"message": "you are already registered", "result": false, "token": asdwasdasd}

How I am going to get for example "token" and save it?

Comment: This HTML may contain a hint what went wrong or what you're doing wrong.  Can you post it here?

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: `let token = connection["token"]?.string`
In your code you already get the token?

Comment: No, it can not get pass "if let value..." loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For saving tokens, I would recommend putting it into the keychain. If you are familiar with NSUserDefaults, the keychain acts similarly except that it adds a security layer to what you're storing. (for more information on how the keychain works, look at [Apple's Keychain Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH203-TP1))

Using keychain through Apple's API can be a bit convoluted, so I use the [KeychainAccess library](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess) to give me a friendlier API. The UICKeyChainStore documentation gives a very succinct tutorial on how to use the library so I will reference you there for implementation (see KeychainAccess link above).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, now its working as I wanted...

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON { response in        
                guard response.result.error == nil else {
                    print(response.result.error!)
                    return
                }
                if let json: NSDictionary = response.result.value as? NSDictionary {
                let result = json["result"]!.stringValue
                    print(result)
                    let token = json["token"] as! String
                    print(token)

            }
    }
```